# How can I delete the bullet generated in acronyms chapter?

Tags: chapters, acronyms, automation, bullets

In acronyms page, integrated in main menu I'm using the below code, but a bullet is generated in first acronym (see picture)

```
\chapter*{Acronyms}

\begin{acronym}[TST] % Give the longest acronym here
\acro{API}{\emph{Application Programming Interface}}
\acro{AI}{\emph{Artificial Intelligence}}
\acro{TST}{\emph{Test}}
\end{acronym}
```

[image]

Comment: If I take your code fragment and place it in a small test document, I end up with https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRMcp.png which is the expected output. Since I can't reproduce the output you get, please prepare a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) and add it to your question. Do you get any error messages upon compiling your document?